# How to correctly decode Google Translate API answers?

Tags: delphi, url, decode, google-translate

I'm communicating with the Google Translate API. I can send my request and get an answer. The only problem is that some special characters are encoded. For exemple :

"**The clock**" (EN) will be translated to "**L'horloge**" (FR)

The API will send me this text `L\u0026#39;horloge`. How can I convert such cases into unicode string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is JSON unicode and HTML encoding.

I suggest you to get superobject to decode JSON:
http://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/#svn/trunk

```
uses msxml, HTTPapp, superobject;
var
  xml: IXMLHTTPRequest;
begin
  xml := CoXMLHTTP.Create;
  xml.open('GET', 'http://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?  key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&q=The%20clock&source=en&target=fr', False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  xml.send('');
  Caption := HTMLDecode(SO(xml.responseText)  ['data.translations[0].translatedText'].AsString);
end;
```

Comment: This is well working :) Didn't even know this library. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can decode them by using the following function:

```
function unescapeUTF8EscapeSeq($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i",
        create_function('$matches',
            'return html_entity_decode(\'&#x\'.$matches[1].\';\', ENT_QUOTES, \'UTF-8\');'
        ), $str);
}
```

If you like, you can try it out [here](http://www.flyingpie.nl/decode.php)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this doens't works all the time. The API send both code : Unicode (like "\u0026" or "\u0035" and so on) and HTML (tag is either an ASCII code like "#39" or an HTML tag like "lt" or "gt" (which stand for < and >)).